# What is the easiest way to do inter process communication between c# and c?

Tags: c#, c, ipc

I have one C# application and C application and I want the C# application to send 2 integers to the other 1(c)

What's the easiest way to do this? (It doesn't have to be the most elegant one)
My C# application is hosted on a Ubuntu operating system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Hi I have created c program and .net application both. Also i have hosted my .net application in ubuntu. Also i have created sample c program. I am lookign for how can establish communication between both of these?

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is only to send the parameters or values to a C function, I can suggest that you consider using P/Invoke. Then you talk about *Ubuntu operating system*, which suggests you either would be using Mono or .NET Core; consider reading this [Native Interoperability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop) — in case of Mono, [this would help](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/).

COM and other interops would require that you write C programs in a way that they can expose themselves out to the .NET framework. If writing the libraries as exposed, is not possible (such as precompiled libraries), then you would be able to have this done using [named pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx). They are the pipes, which are used for communication within processes.

Comment: Thanks. I would follow named pipes. Can you share me few links which will help me out?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole, the named pipes link contains other references at the bottom.